# MongoDB - combining several input documents into one output document using an aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've seen a number of questions on SO that seem to be similar to mine but I couldn't find an answer to my problem. If so, please point me to it.

I have a number of documents that are the output of a group stage in my aggregation pipeline that look like this:

```
{
  _id: "2019-06",
  revenue: 20391.71
},
{
  _id: "2019-03",
  revenue: 10190.44
},
...
```

The `_id` key corresponds to the month, and the `revenue` to the corresponding revenue.

I'd like to get one document containing all the information above, like this:

```
{
  "2019-03": 10190.44,
  "2019-06": 20391.71,
  ...
}
```

It seems like this operation should be kind of easy to do, but I can't get my head around `$mergeObjects` which seems like an obvious candidate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `arrayToObject` with little reshaping

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      _id: null,
      data: {
        $push: {
          "k": "$_id",
          "v": "$revenue"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "res": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$data"
      },
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EBu7KigVRaj)

Comment: that's great; any chance to remove the `res` key and just have its contents at the root level? (Otherwise, there is surely a possibility to have this cleaned up in some postprocessing, thanks anyway.)

Comment: Yes. [replaceRoot](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pED71KZssKA) will help you. See the sample there.